# Mysql error in Klarna cron to clean logs - Error: 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''store_id'' in ''where clause'',

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3, klarna

Klarna cron to clean the log throws the error and cron job failed:

Table: `cron_schedule`

job_code : `klarna_core_clean_logs`

Error: `` 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''store_id'' in ''where clause'', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `klarna_logs` AS `main_table` WHERE (`store_id` = ''0'') AND (`created_at` <= ''2021-07-14'')' ``

Answer (score 2):

I See, `vendor/klarna/module-core/etc/db_schema.xml` does not have store_id in the "column" tag
But " `$logs->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $store->getId());"` in `vendor/klarna/module-core/Cron/CleanLogs.php:141`

I think this causes the error in cron jobs.

Created a patch file to resolve this issue

```
diff --git a/vendor/klarna/module-core/Cron/CleanLogs.php b/vendor/klarna/module-core/Cron/CleanLogs.php
index a2910a8..28f684c 100644
--- a/vendor/klarna/module-core/Cron/CleanLogs.php
+++ b/vendor/klarna/module-core/Cron/CleanLogs.php
@@ -138,7 +138,6 @@ class CleanLogs
         $lifetime *= self::SECONDSINDAY;

         $logs = $this->logCollectionFactory->create();
-        $logs->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $store->getId());
         $logs->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['to' => date("Y-m-d", time() - $lifetime)]);

         return $logs;
```